# How to make UIBarButton not greyed out when disabled?

Tags: ios, swift, customization, uibarbuttonitem

I have a `UIBarButton saveBarButton` to save an image of the screen to the camera roll. When the user presses the `saveBarButton` the image is saved and the `UIBarButton saveBarButton` changes to the `UIImage doneIcon`for 1.2 seconds to indicate to the user that the image has been saved. When the `saveBarButton` displays the `doneIcon` I disable `saveBarButton`. However, when I do that the `saveBarButton` is greyed out.

My question is: how do I stop the `UIBarButton` from greying out when disabled?

My code:

```
//create UIBarButton saveBarButton
override func viewDidLoad() {    
    let saveBarButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "saveIcon"), style: .Plain, target: self, action: "save:")
    saveBarButton.tintColor = colorGreyDark
}

//save function called when press saveBarButton
func save(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    //save image
    deselectShape()
    let window: UIWindow! = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow
    let windowImage = capture(window)
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(windowImage
        , nil, nil, nil)

    //Change saveBarButton to indicate to user that image was saved 
    sender.image = UIImage(named: "doneIcon")
    sender.enabled = false //disable saveBarButton
    self.performSelector("canSaveAgain:", withObject: sender, afterDelay: 1.2)
}

//Change saveBarButton to original icon to indicate to user that can save another image
func canSaveAgain(sender: UIBarButtonItem){
    sender.image = UIImage(named: "saveIcon")
    sender.enabled = true //enable saveBarButton
}
```

[To see what I'm talking about.](http://www.gfycat.com/RealisticClassicFlyingfox)

Comment: Have you tried `sender.tintColor = UIColor(red: 51/255, green: 51/255, blue: 51/255, alpha: 1.0)`, where you set the button to enabled = false?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One of ways is to create `UIBarButtonItem` with `customView` and use `userInteractionEnabled` instead `enabled`.

```
let saveBarButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: saveButton)
saveBarButton.customView?.userInteractionEnabled = false
```

Comment: interesting idea...I've actually changed my code now so I don't need to do this at all but thank you for your help! I'll keep this in mind when I need it